# "cargo-build-bpf" Bad CPU type in executable

Tags: anchor, solana-program, cargo

I'm new to Solana dev and was starting up with Anchor on an M1 machine.

While calling `anchor build`, I receive the following error messages:

```
Warning: cargo-build-bpf is deprecated. Please, use cargo-build-sbf
cargo-build-bpf child: /.../solana/install/active_release/bin/cargo-build-sbf --arch bpf
error: command failed: 'cargo': Bad CPU type in executable (os error 86)
```

The versions I have for Solana, Anchor and Rustc are:

```
❯ anchor --version
anchor-cli 0.25.0
❯ solana --version
solana-cli 1.11.10 (src:843e018c; feat:4253057308)
❯ rustc --version
rustc 1.63.0 (4b91a6ea7 2022-08-08)
```

Answer (score 1):

After installing Rust & Cargo you can go this way :

- Rust : `curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh`
- Solana CLI Tool :

  - https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools
  - adding this to ~/.zshrc file

    - `export solana=/Users/reasje/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin`
- SPL Token
  Used for interacting token program

  - `cargo install spl-token-cli`
- Anchor :

  ```
  cargo install --git https://github.com/project-serum/anchor anchor-cli --locked
  ```

  - adding this to ~/.zshrc file

    - `export PATH=/Users/reasje/.cargo/bin:${PATH}`

If none worked check [this](https://github.com/LearnWithArjun/solana-env-setup/blob/main/m1_setup.md).

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal, install rosetta:

> softwareupdate --install-rosetta

Then close the terminal, open a new one and run anchor build again

Answer (score 0):

U have to upgrade solana cli to 1.13.5

sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.13.5/install)"